# Entangled processes

Tags: concurrency, simulation, theory, distributed-computing, computer-science-theory

What is the likelihood of having two separate processes being somehow **entangled** despite the nonexistence of any ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) communication between them? What I mean by entangled is showing a dependency behaviour, or causality, whereby the behaviour of one process is affected by something the other process is doing.

Is there a way to measure this dependency?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say this is absolutely too broad, but as at least one suggestion I can say that _performance_ of one process (which is part of its behavior, of cource) will definitely depend on what other processes are doing.

Comment: is there a way to quantify this dependency? for instance by using their memory/CPU usage? or by looking at their interactions with OS?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I can not tell this.